# How to handle current user in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

(This is for a single-page Javascript application where certain user information is embedded in the layout)

I'm looking to constrain my routes depending on the user's permissions and allow them to view their own information via the route `/current`. That is, if they're a `user`, they can access only routes that a user can access, and while they cannot view other `user` information, they are allowed to view their own. I'm setting this up using constraints:

```
scope :users, constraints: UserConstraint.new do
    get '/:id/' => 'users#show'
end
```

This works when a user wants to visit the route with their `id`, but I don't want to embed their `id` into the page; I would like the user to be able to access `/users/current` and access their information. I thought of doing something like

```
scope :users, constraints: ->(req) {
    req.params[:id] = RequestCurrentUser.new(req).user.id if req.params[:id] == 'current'
} do
    get '/:id/' => 'users#show'
end
```

But the controller sees `id=current` rather than `id=1`. Is it possible to accomplish this, or is there a better way?

Comment: Use sessions in order to keep information like that around. You can also use the Devise gem to handle user sign up / sign in. It will do all the session work for you.

Comment: I do keep user's information in a session via a session cookie, which holds a `key`, and access it in the `RequestCurrentUser.new(req)` call. I'm specifically asking about routing in this case.

Comment: I do have serializers set up depending on the access a user has (`user` can't access the amount of information `admin` can) but that still doesn't solve getting `/users/:id` set up to allow someone to visit `/users/current` and get their information via the routes.

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to handling this in the routing layer with complicated constraints, why not simply provide some sort of `UsersController#current` endpoint that just returns the current_user as json?

```
class UsersController
  # ...

  def current # or def show
    render json: current_user
  end

  # ...
end
```

Best to simply have some sort of endpoint that requires authentication and renders the authenticated user rather than dynamically route based on authentication.

Comment: I am currently doing that but I think it's actually kind of silly to have two controller actions that do essentially the same thing, `show` and `current`. I would rather do them both in `show` if possible...

Comment: I thought that users couldn't view other users' information, only their own. Why do both endpoints exist?

Comment: A separate action is the best way to do it because the lookup method for the current user versus a user ID is completely different. It's not logic that should be in the routes config. You can extract shared method behaviour in the controller.